# Can anyone see the commits after I deleted the fork repo?

Tags: github

I have forked a repo from a public one.
And then I pushed 2 commits to my forked repo with some password info.
Then I deleted this fork repo quickly.
Finally I re-forked it in the same name.
Will the previous commits history never be seen？